# How to use services within a singleton-class Spring Boot (wire up different services with a "usual" class)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to run a few tests for my Spring-Boot application and I keep running into a NullPointerException within a singleton. I have the following setup:

```
@Service
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void saveProject(ProjectDto projectDto) {        
        ProjectEntity projectEntity = ProjectConverter.getInstance().convertDtoToEntityWithDefaultFactory(projectDto);
        entityManager.persist(projectEntity);
        entityManager.flush();
    }
}
```

And the following Singleton:

```
@ComponentScan(myServicePackageImpl)
public class ProjectConverter {

    private static ProjectConverter projectConverterInstance;

    @Autowired
    private FactoryEntityService factoryService;

    public static ProjectConverter getInstance() {
        if (projectConverterInstance == null) {
            projectConverterInstance = new ProjectConverter();
        }
        return projectConverterInstance;
    }

    private ProjectConverter() {
    }

    @Transactional
    public ProjectEntity convertDtoToEntityWithDefaultFactory(ProjectDto projectDto) {
        FactoryEntity defaultFactory = this.factoryService.
                getDefaultFactoryEntity();
    //...
    }
}
```

Now I read [this article](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/spring-mvc-java-autowired-component-null-repository-service/) that said that you might run into a `NullPointerException` if you instantiate your class manually (which I am doing in the singleton) - now my question: How can I workaround that? I got my Converter Class that needs to be some database-stuff which can be done within another Service. For me that means that I cannot only have static members in my class (since I use Autowired services). Is it even possible to wire up two services in a "usual class"?

Comment: What is your motivation for making this a singleton? That's nearly always an antipattern.

Comment: @chrylis To be honest my motivation was that I wasn't sure how to do it another way. As this is a converter, usually I had a static `convertDtoToEntity`-method. Sadly I needed to do some more stuff including querying the database, why I wanted to include services and the EntityManager, so I needed it to be non-static any more I guess.. - so it's probably more or less a workaround for things you could solve differnetly maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I read this article that said that you might run into a
>   NullPointerException if you instantiate your class manually (which I
>   am doing in the singleton).

You don't have to initialize the `ProjectConverter` by yourself. You can just mark it as `@Component` and Spring shall create a Bean of this class for you.

**Code Snippet:**

```
@Component
public class ProjectConverter { ... }
```